# Find and then prove the supremum of set X

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Set X is defined with $$\sqrt {(x (x + 1))}/(2 x + 1)$$, x > 0. 
I can't prove that for every epsilon greater than zero there exists an t > 0 such that $$1/2 - \sqrt{(t (t + 1))}/(2 t + 1) < \epsilon.$$
Every other step I get.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{\sqrt{x(x+1)}}{2x+1}\le \frac{1}{2}$$ for $x>0$, this is true, multiplying by $2$ and squaring we get
$$4x(x+1)\le 4x^2+4x+1$$
This is true since we get $$0\le 1$$

Comment: I know that it is greater than zero, but how can I squeeze it between zero and epsilon? Can't I just then replace 1/2 with 1 and still get a true statement?

Comment: Sorry those are two seperate questions, in the second one I mean that if I replace 1/2 with 1 wouldn't I by definition also get that supX = 1 instead of 1/2?